# Unable to Play HTML Embedded Youtube Video

Tags: html, video, youtube

I am trying to embed a youtube video onto my website using HTML but whenever I try to play it this error comes up:

An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: hl1cNylLQh5f_AZE)
Learn More

My HTML code is:

```
<div>
  <iframe width="600" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=YuAya0hRjwU" 
   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

How do I get the video to play?

Answer (score 2):

Your link probably isn't valid. Copy the link and paste on a browser to be sure it's valid.

You should try copying the video url, not the url you find on the browser.
Better still, on YouTube try sharing as an embedded link, and copy the link from there.

Answer (score 2):

Your link has wrong format: https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=YuAya0hRjwU.

 There is no using something like `/embed?v=` in a Youtube embed link.

Try this correct format:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/YuAya0hRjwU

example code:

```
<div>
  <iframe width="600" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YuAya0hRjwU" 
   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```